# Whats the reason for passing a math.pi (pi number) in the hough function?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

i don't know the reason for passing a number for threshold in the hough function

```
cv.HoughLines(src, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180, 30, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on OpenCV's documentation [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines):

```c
HoughLines(InputArray image, OutputArray lines, double rho, double theta, int threshold, double srn=0, double stn=0 )
```

the fourth parameter is `theta` which refers to:

> **theta** – Angle resolution of the accumulator in **radians**.

In order to convert `d` degrees to radians, you should multiply `d` by `Math.Pi` and divide it by 180. In your example, the angle resolution is set to **1 degree** or `Math.Pi / 180` radians.